# how to add console arguments to cmakelist + vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, command-line-arguments

I have been trying to add console arguments eg. "hello world.txt" to be accessible as arguments in int main(int argc, char* argv[]).

Every time when I print argc and argv I have just one element, the absolute directory of main.exe.

I tried in launch.json in :args":[] and in cmakelist.txt as a add_definition but it did not work
Cmakelist.txt configuration

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(firstProject VERSION 0.1.0)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
include(CTest)
include_directories(headers)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
enable_testing()

add_executable(firstProject main.cpp ala.cpp "headers/ala.h")
set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})

include(CPack)
```

Launch.json configuration:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        //CMAKE ADDITIONAL CONFIGURATION
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            // Resolved by CMake Tools:
            "program": "${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [
                {

                    "name": "${workspaceFolder}",
                    "value": "$PATH:${command:cmake.launchTargetDirectory}"
                }
            ],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "C/C++: g++.exe build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Do I do use wrong method or I have some problem with cmake configuration?

Comment: Don't you add them here: `"args": [],` in your `launch.json`, CMake has nothing to do with command line arguments.

Comment: Ok I checked again in the debug mode it works but when I click run a code it doesn't. Is it possibility that it will work in run a code? How to do this. @drescherjm

Comment: Related: [https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/924](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/924)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks drescherjm for your comment!

It was enough to add:

```
"cmake.debugConfig": {
    "args": [
        "-first", 
        "-second"
    ]
 }
```

in settings.json